# Polynomial, pseudoprimes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

1) By Fermat's Little Theorem , given a polynomial of the form $f(x) = x - c$, if $p$ is a prime, then the sum of the pth powers of the roots of f is congruent to the sum of the first powers $\pmod p)$.
Can you explain that how the cited above statement is true?

2) I know Fibonacci numbers. How one can name it f(x) = $x^2 - x -1$ is Fibonacci polynomial? if a, b are roots of f(x),The $n$th term of the Lucas sequence is just $L_n = a^n + b^n,$ and so, since $a + b = 1,$ it follows from Fermat's Little Theorem that $L_p = 1 \pmod p$ for every prime p. Can you explain these relations with an example.

Comment: The roots of the Fibonacci Polynomial are $$\phi = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ It's called the Golden Ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, The root of $f(x) = x - c$ is $c$, obviously. So, the sum of $p$th powers of roots of $f$ is $c^p$ which by Fermat's Little Theorem is congruent to $c \pmod p$ which is the first power.

For the second one, the roots of the Fibonacci Polynomial are

$$\phi = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

So, if we add them we get $1$. Hence, $a+b=1$.
Now,

$$L_p \equiv a^p + b^p \equiv a + b \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

We used Fermat's Little Theorem over here. What did you not understand?

Comment: ! take the non-obvious case. I mean if f has 3 roots then what will happen?

Comment: @Gagan How can a linear polynomial have 3 roots? Anyway it doesn't matter. While the roots are integers, $x^p \equiv x \pmod p$.

Comment: @Gagan! Okay. can you see my second question please

Comment: @Gagan I've updated my answer.

Comment: ! well, explain the last step that, how did you apply Fermat little theorem to L_p = 1 (mod p)

Comment: @Gagan Okay. What's $a^p \pmod p$? $a$. What's $b^p  \pmod p$? $b$. So, what's $a^p +b^p \pmod p$? $a+b$. But we know that $a+b=1$. So, it's $1 \pmod p$.